# Une petite question sur l'utilisation des pronoms avec « ma vie »

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, déterminants

Pourquoi disons-nous « Vous avez changé ma vie » et non « Vous m'avez changé la vie » ?

D'un autre côté, pourquoi disons-nous « Vous m'avez sauvé la vie » et non « Vous avez sauvé ma vie » ?

Apparemment, les deux phrases ci-dessus sont correctes, selon @Laure. Mais est-il possible de répondre à cette question : laquelle de ces phrases est utilisée le plus souvent ?

Comment: « [Vous m'avez changé la vie](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=&as_epq=Vous+m%27avez+chang%C3%A9+la+vie&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=) » et « [Vous avez sauvé ma vie](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=&as_epq=Vous+avez+sauv%C3%A9+ma+vie&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=) » se disent et sont corrects.  S'il s'agit donc d'un contexte particulier il faut le préciser dans la question.

Comment: @Laure Oui, je veux en effet parler du pronom personnel ; je me suis trompé au sujet de pronom refléchi; J'ai bien modifié le titre de ma question. (À mon défense, c'est minuit maitenant à Los Angeles; et il faut que je me couche maitenant. :-) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Ngram montre qu'il y a une nette préférence pour « m'avoir sauvé la vie » par rapport « avoir sauvé ma vie », et que la forme « m'avoir changé la vie » est très rare.

[image]

Les deux formes ne sont pas totalement équivalentes.

> Tu m'as sauvé la vie.

met l'emphase sur la personne qui a sauvé la vie, alors que

> Tu as sauvé ma vie.

insiste plus sur le fait que c'est sa vie qui a été sauvée.

« Tu m'as changé la vie » sonne bizarre, mais je ne sais pas vraiment dire pourquoi car la phrase « ça me change la vie » est courante.

Comment: Votre remarque concernant «ça me change la vie» est intéressante, car c’est en effet courant. Je crois qu'elle s'applique surtout pour de petits évènements qui surviennent à répétition (pensons par exemple à un cours de danse pour un adulte qui n'avait jamais appris, qui ne prend pas beaucoup de temps, mais revient une ou deux fois par semaine, régulièrement). «Ça a changé ma vie», par contre, sous-entend un changement beaucoup plus profond, ou du moins est-ce ainsi que je le comprendrais...

Comment: Contrairement à vous deux, je ne connais pas « ça me change la vie », est-ce que c'est pareil que _ça fait changement dans ma vie_ ? Merci.

Comment: @redahabsinpeach  Probablement mais « faire changement » n'est pas très courant ici. On dit plutôt « fait un changement » ou « fait du changement », par exemple: « Ça fait un gros changement dans ma vie ».

Comment: @red ahabs in peach  Est-ce que «ça (me) change le mal de place» serait plus naturel et commun?

Comment: @jlliagre Merci, je comprends, je trouve _ça fait changement_ plus usuel seul que suivi d'un complément comme ds. mon précédent commentaire. Mon réflexe avec _gros changement_ c'est que c'est un registre moins soutenu, et à l'oral j'aurais un pronom _me_ devant le verbe qui témoignerait de ça et donc j'aurais _la_ vie etc. Ça se peut fort bien que je confonde un truc plus usuel avec une expression plus figée, et ça me donne une impression de confusion des genres. Parfois j'ai aussi simplement une crampe de cerveau.

Comment: @Feelew Pour moi, tout à fait. Merci !

Comment: Plutôt tendance «ça (me) fait changement» que «ça (me) fait du changement» moi aussi, mais la proximité culturelle et géographique joue sans doute.